# Trying to fetch URL on a person ID using the LinkedIn /rest API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am fetching posts for LinkedIn API, and in the commentary if a person is mentioned, I get `@[Person Name](urn:li:person:hashid)`, and I would like to take the person ID and fetch more info (particularly a url to get to this person's page).

I have tried:

`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/people?ids=List(urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3AhashId1,urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3AhashId2)`

```
Content-Type: application/json
X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
LinkedIn-Version: 202305
X-RestLi-Method: BATCH_GET
```

And I am getting 400 as a status response:

```
{
    "results": {},
    "statuses": {},
    "errors": {
        "urn:li:person:hashId1": {
            "status": 400
        },
        "urn:li:person:hashId2": {
            "status": 400
        }
    }
}
```

I would assume these person IDs need to be correct since they are being returned in the other endpoint, and that they are not restricted since I get an author ID for one of these as well on the post endpoint, and it gives me details on the user.